# Rails with Aptana IDE : intellisense with methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ide, aptana

I'm using Aptana IDE for my Rails project.

when I choose a method of a class. (i.e. `CSV.parse_line`), the IDE doesn't present to me the method's arguments.

How can I fix this?